# Dynamic URL in odoo form

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can I create a dynamic link in the odoo formview

for example
Static text=http://maps.chef-debiscuit.com/map.php?sheetID=

dynamic text = record id

(solution) http://maps.chef-debiscuit.com/map.php?sheetID=32

For the moment i only have

```
<a href="http://maps.chef-debiscuit.com/map.php?sheetID=" target="_blank">View on Map</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0) Create new computed field x_url

1) copy ID -> Field x_copy_id

2) Convert x_copy_id to string

3) Combine static text with IDCOPY

```
for record in self:
IDCOPY = str(record['x_copy_id'])
record['x_url']='http:///maps.chef-debiscuit.com/map.php?sheetID='+IDCOPY
```